# How to ask Mathematica to subtract each adjacent pair in a list, and then, sum them?

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, numerics, summation

If I have a list of numbers as (the number of elements in this list is even)

```
list={1,23,32,54,65,76,87,98,109,110,...}
```

How can I ask Mathematica to subtract each adjacent pair, and then, sum them, i.e. compute this value

$sum=(...)+(110-109)+(98-87)+(76-65)+(54-32)+(23-1)$

Comment: `Total@BlockMap[Subtract @@ # &, Reverse@list, 2]`?

Comment: ... or `Total[#[[2 ;; ;; 2]] - #[[;; ;; 2]]] &@list`, or `Total@Differences[list][[;; ;; 2]]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list = {1, 23, 32, 54, 65, 76, 87, 98, 109, 110};

Total @ Differences[list][[;; ;; 2]]
```

> ```
> 67
> ```

Also

```
(-1)^Range[Length @ #]. # & @ list
```

> ```
> 67
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add other ways:

```
Total[(#[[2]] - #[[1]]) & /@ Partition[list, 2]]
```

(* 67 *)

```
Total@Flatten[Differences /@ Partition[list, 2]]
```

Comment: similar to your first answer you can write `Total[(#2 - #1) & @@@ Partition[list, 2]]`

Comment: Even simpler: `Total[-Subtract @@@ Partition[list, 2]]`

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 23, 32, 54, 65, 76, 87, 98, 109, 110};
PadRight[{-1, 1}, Length@list, {-1, 1}] . list
```

> `67`

Comment: For my own learning: if you add 111 to the end of the list, the result is -44. Is this the standard way of padding such a list or the choice of {-1,1} is arbitrary?

Comment: @Syed Since the sequence is -1,1,-1,1,…,-1,1,-1 for the new case, the last term is 111*(-1),so the result become 67+111*(-1)=-44

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 23, 32, 54, 65, 76, 87, 98, 109, 110};
```

Using `SequenceCases`

```
Total @ SequenceCases[list, {a_, b_} :> b - a]
```

67

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 23, 32, 54, 65, 76, 87, 98, 109, 110};
```

Using `MovingMap`:

```
Total@(#2 - #1 & @@@ MovingMap[# &, list, 1][[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]])

(*67*)
```